# Must use destructuring theme assignment react/destructuring-assignment

Tags: typescript, typescript-eslint

I am trying to start a typescript project but i'm getting a bunch of errors relating to   "Line 92:27:  Must use destructuring theme assignment  react/destructuring-assignment". I have about 10 of these errors.

The error specifically for above is relating to the code for line 92 is:

```
<StyledClose color={theme.colors.textSubtle} onClick={removeThisPopup} />
```

This is apart of this overall code which onClick={removeThisPopup} is used towards the bottom of the code.

```
export default function PopupItem({
  removeAfterMs,
  content,
  popKey
}: {
  removeAfterMs: number | null
  content: PopupContent
  popKey: string
}) {
  const removePopup = useRemovePopup()
  const removeThisPopup = useCallback(() => removePopup(popKey), [popKey, removePopup])
  useEffect(() => {
    if (removeAfterMs === null) return undefined

    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      removeThisPopup()
    }, removeAfterMs)

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeout)
    }
  }, [removeAfterMs, removeThisPopup])

  const theme = useContext(ThemeContext)

  let popupContent
  if ('txn' in content) {
    const {
      txn: { hash, success, summary }
    } = content
    popupContent = <TransactionPopup hash={hash} success={success} summary={summary} />
  } else if ('listUpdate' in content) {
    const {
      listUpdate: { listUrl, oldList, newList, auto }
    } = content
    popupContent = <ListUpdatePopup popKey={popKey} listUrl={listUrl} oldList={oldList} newList={newList} auto={auto} />
  }

  const faderStyle = useSpring({
    from: { width: '100%' },
    to: { width: '0%' },
    config: { duration: removeAfterMs ?? undefined }
  })

  return (
    <Popup>
      <StyledClose color={theme.colors.textSubtle} onClick={removeThisPopup} />
      {popupContent}
      {removeAfterMs !== null ? <AnimatedFader style={faderStyle} /> : null}
    </Popup>
  )
```

I have found that this react/destructuring-assignment issue is due to eslint.. specifcally airbnb but i am unsure how to amend the code above to abide by the rule.

Thanks.

Update on 'theme' is already declared in the upper scope:

```
import React, { useCallback, useContext, useEffect } from 'react'
import { X } from 'react-feather'
import { animated, useSpring } from 'react-spring'
import styled, { ThemeContext } from 'styled-components'
// import { animated } from 'react-spring'
import { PopupContent } from '../../state/application/actions'
import { useRemovePopup } from '../../state/application/hooks'
import ListUpdatePopup from './ListUpdatePopup'
import TransactionPopup from './TransactionPopup'

const theme = useContext(ThemeContext)
const { colors } = theme
const { textSubtle } = colors

export const StyledClose = styled(X)`
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;

  :hover {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
`
export const Popup = styled.div`
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.invertedContrast};
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-right: 35px;
  overflow: hidden;

  ${({ theme }) => theme.mediaQueries.sm} {
    min-width: 290px;
  }
`
const Fader = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.tertiary};
`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, to align with  eslint rules you need to destructure the theme object.

For example:

```js
const theme = useContext(ThemeContext)
const { colors } = theme
const { textSubtle } = colors
```

Then pass textSubtle to StyledClose component

```
<StyledClose color={textSubtle} onClick={removeThisPopup} />
```

This should remove the warnings you are seeing.

Comment: it went away! thanks! Time to do this for all of them!

Comment: Now that we have declared theme, i get ```'theme' is already declared in the upper scope    ``` for the code ```background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.invertedContrast};```

Comment: Can you give some more context please? Are you using styled components?

Comment: I've added a update on my post with more of the code